# Update application in windowsphone store

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an application, made in cordova, in windows phone store, which is developed for WP7 OS. If my new, updated version is also developed for WP7 OS, then everything works fine. Files, cache, images are still in app sandbox after update.

Problem appears when I'm trying to make exactly the same update, but I'm using project for WP8. When I do that kind of update, I still have one copy of that application (I mean it is the same position at application list in my phone, not second app on list with the same name), but my previously created files/cache/images disappears.

In WMAppManifest.xml I have the same ProductID

In AssemblyInfo.cs I have the same Guid.

I've also tried to use VB option "convert project to WP8.0" - same result.

Application which is causing this problem is running through windows market - it its developer app only for closed group of people.

Comment: Anyone can help me? It's really big problem for me

Answer (score 1):

If you're side loading app from VS then you'll need to change the `ProductID` for the different version of the app as it is this that the OS uses to distinguish between apps.
If they are the same the OS will treat the installation of the second app as a replacement of the first.

This is not the case with apps from the store as when your app is repackaged for deployment a new GUID is generated for the ProductID.

If you have two packages, targeting different OS versions, for the an app then you can't install both versions on one device.

Comment: Application which is causing this problem is running through windows market - it its developer app only for closed group of people.

Comment: I dont want to install both, I want old version developed for WP7 to keep cache and data after update. Update is new version developer for WP8.